# Implement an action filter that controls the HTTPStatus code based on the result of the action method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have ASP.NETCORE 3.1 WEBAPI , Azure SQL server as the database for an application.

In order to avoid repetitive code, I thought of implementing a filter which will decide the HTTP Status code based on the result return from the API endpoint. The idea here is remove the duplicate code related to setting up the result returned along with HTTP Status code always.

I wanted to know is it good practice to move away from the traditional approach of sending the response back to client with result and appropriate HTTP Status code from the action method itself or delegate it to an action filter post execution of the action method.

**Code (Without Filter):**

```
[HttpGet("{param1:long}", Name = "GetData")]
[ResponseCache(CacheProfileName = "Never")]
[ProducesResponseType(200)]
[ProducesResponseType(400)]
[ProducesResponseType(500)]
public async Task<ActionResult<TestModel>> GetData(long param1)
{
    var result = await _testService.GetData(param1);
    return result is null ? NotFound() : (ActionResult<TestModel>)Ok(result);
}
```

**Code (With Filter)**

```
[HttpGet("{param1:long}", Name = "GetData")]
[ResponseCache(CacheProfileName = "Never")]
[ProducesResponseType(200)]
[ProducesResponseType(400)]
[ProducesResponseType(500)]
[ServiceFilter(typeof(StatusFilter))]
public async Task<ActionResult<TestModel>> GetData(long param1)=>    
  await _testService.GetData(param1);       


// Filter to handle the HTTP Status code
public class StatusFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var value = ((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult)context.Result).Value;
        if (value is null)
        {
            context.Result = new NotFoundResult(value);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Result = new OkObjectResult(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any better approach in order to implement it.

Can anyone help me here by providing their guidance?

Comment: The controller methods are identical in both cases, so it's not clear to me how the filter helps. The controller is still deciding whether to return 404 or 200. Another option would be a generic method in a base controller or static class. That generic method takes an object (`result`) and returns either an Ok or NotFound response depending on whether the object is null.

Comment: Thanks @ScottHannen for the response. I have updated the code now with all the details

Comment: How about replacing the action filters with result filter in this case? Any thoughts on it

Comment: A result filter is closer to what you're trying to do. It's focused on changing the result.